# ExtJS not rendering components correctly

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5, sencha-cmd

I'm using ExtJS 5.1.

Every time I run `sencha app build` or `sencha app refresh`, there's a chance that something will go wrong and it will make the components be rendered completely wrong on the screen. This image can explain better:

[image: Bad rendering]

And this is how it should look like:

[image: How it should be]

The only solution I have so far is to run those commands repeatedly until the application renders correctly.

This happens in all browsers, and it's not related to cache. Also SenchaCMD does not throw any errors that I can relate to this problem.

Comment: I had similar issues. They seem to have gone with upgrade to version 6 (both CMD and Ext JS).

Comment: Is there any major difference in version 6, like from 4 to 5? Upgrading to 5 left our application useless for a very long time.

Comment: The difference in JS code between 5 and 6 is not that big as between 4 and 5 (I can't even recall if I had to change anything though I did the upgrade only a month ago!). The difference is, though, in how the workspace is organised, folder locations, `app.json` and `package.json` files etc. Also bear in mind that you need to use `classic` toolkit only.

Comment: You can also try to upgrade CMD only to version 6 first. It is *supposed* to work with Ext JS 5, and it worked for me, but I still had some weird issues with using touch themes.

Answer (score 3):

`sencha app refresh` will not build the CSS and therefore will not affect the style of the components. `sencha app build` should build the CSS but during development I tend to use `sencha app watch` to update the CSS.

Comment: And for building SASS only I use "sencha ant sass" a lot.

Comment: The beauty about `sencha app watch` is that it will listen to file changes and build the SASS without any re-executing. Yes, it will rebuild the metadata also so it'll take a bit of time but for me it only takes 5 seconds for the whole process while always running other commands makes me switch back and takes about the same time... just with app watch I don't have to do anything.